# What is the source of these comic book panels of the Batmobile garage?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, episode-identification

What is the source of these comic book panels of the Batmobile garage?

[image: comic book panel of the Batmobile garage]

[image: comic book panel of the Batmobile garage]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first image is from [*Batman* Volume 1, Issue #615](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_615), part of the *Hush* storyline.

The second one has, at the least, shown up on the "[Batmobile, Burn Rubber](https://www.coolstuffinc.com/p/VS+System/Batmobile%2C+Burn+Rubber)" card for the VS System CCG.

Comment: For what it is worth, my search methodology basically consisted of pasting the images into images.google.com and seeing what came up.